# How to add a CSS class only when it is in Top 0

Tags: javascript

(sorry for my bad English language)

I have this script that when I scroll the page of 100px adds the class: "shadow-cat". It works perfectly:

```
document.documentElement.className = "js";

$(window).scroll( function() {

    if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 100 ) {
        $(".navigation").addClass("shadow-cat");
    } else {
        $(".navigation").removeClass("shadow-cat");
    }

});
```

But I would like a different behavior:
the shadow-cat class must be added only when it is at top 0, not before.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you show no research-effort whatsoever and the task is absolutely trivial.

Comment: Have you tried  $(document).scrollTop() == 100 ??

Comment: Why not `== 0` instead of `> 100`?

Comment: When I tell my computer `say("a")` he says "a", what to do if I want him to say "b" instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the condition `$(document).scrollTop() > 100` to like `$(document).scrollTop() == 100` then if the window scrolled to 0 show-cat will be added to the element. if it is scrolled a bit then the class will be removed.

Comment: this has a value of 100: (document).scrollTop() == 100   in my case I need the class to be added to the top position 0.
I tried to change it to: $(document).scrollTop() == 0  but in this case the class is added immediately and removed as soon as I scroll

Comment: Then you can give a threshold of 30. Then the condition would be ‘=<30’

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll( function() {

    if ( $(document).scrollTop() > 100 ) {
        $("header").addClass("active");
    } else if($(document).scrollTop() == 0){
        $("header").removeClass("active");
    }

});
```

```css
body{
height: 5000px;
}
header{
background:black;
width:100%;
height: 200px;
position:fixed;
}
.active{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
```